# Replace CATransition animation with UIView animation

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-animation

Could anyone guide me how I can perform the following CATransition animation:

```
        let animation = CATransition()
        animation.duration = 0.25
        animation.type = CATransitionType.push
        animation.subtype = CATransitionSubtype(rawValue: CATransitionSubtype.fromTop.rawValue)
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        textLabel.layer.add(animation, forKey: "text-change")
```

Using UIView.animate ? I would like to combine this with another animation I am performing.

I tried using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622574-transition but have had little luck so far. Thanks.

Comment: You can combine your animation with another animation, as is. Even a view animation is ultimately a layer animation, so it makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any idea how I can combine a UIView.animation with a CATransition?